# N2 CMS SlidingCurtain control is not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, n2, n2cms

I just set up a new N2 site by starting with the MVC 2 Web Application template in Visual Studio, then following the directions in **N2 CMS Developer Documentation** in the section *Integrating with Existing ASP.NET MVC Application*.  I have the basic site running now, but with one problem: the sliding curtain widget that holds the administrative controls is not visible in the upper right corner (when logged in, of course).

I can make it visible the hard way by using Firebug to locate it in the DOM, and then disabling a couple of the CSS positioning elements.  Once I do that, it seems to work normally.  After I open it that way, I can click the various controls, or close it up (and I see the animation).  But then it's off screen again.

My master page has the sliding curtain just inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<body>
<n2:SlidingCurtain runat="server">
    <n2:ControlPanel runat="server" />
</n2:SlidingCurtain>
...
```

The site.css file generated in the base MVC site doesn't seem to do any positioning that would affect this.

Firebug shows that right after by `<body>` tag, I have this:

```
<div class="sc" id="SC" style="top: -2px; left: -574px;"><div class="scContent">
....
```

The style for `<div class="sc" ...>` is

```
element.style {
left:-574px;
top:-2px;
}
.sc {
background:#FFFFFF none repeat-x scroll 0 0;
border-color:#CCCCBB;
border-style:none solid solid none;
border-width:1px;
left:-200px;
position:fixed;
top:-200px;
z-index:990;
}
```

If I disable both `top:` and both `left:` rules, the widget appears.

**EDIT**
I have some more clues.  My problem happens in Firefox, but not IE.  The jQuery code that opens and closes the control is in /N2/Resources/Js/parts.js.  When I use Firebug to put some breakpoints on the functions that implement the open and close operations, the control works.